# Query Between two date fields

Tags: ms-access

I have one table of employees with a column called Hire Date. And I have another table of orders and every order has a date when it was processed.
Now I want to figure out how many orders this employee made in the first 30 days from his hire date. I made a query with DateAdd function in access and made a column with all employees 30 days after hire date, now I want to make a query of orders between hire date and 30 days after hire date.[query from 30 days after hire date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3XYc.png)

Comment: Please share the query you already have

Answer (score 0):

Assume Employees table has EmpCode and Orders table has EmpCode too

It will be something like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM Orders INNER JOIN Employees ON Orders.EmpCode = Employees.EmpCode
WHERE EmpCode = 'ABCD' AND DateAdd ( d, 30, Employees.HireDate) > Orders.OrdDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Expand your query to include the EmployeeId. Then it could be:

```
Select 
    YourQuery.FirstName, YourQuery.LastName, Count(OrderTable.*) As OrderCount
From
    YourQuery,
    OrderTable
Where
    OrderTable.EmplyoyeeId = YourQuery.EmplyoyeeId
    And
    OrderTable.OrderDate Between YourQuery.[Hire Date] And YourQuery.[30 days after]
Group By
    YourQuery.FirstName, 
    YourQuery.LastName
```